# Installing dryscrape (python library for web scraping) in Google Colab

Tags: python, web-scraping, pip, google-colaboratory, dryscrape

I was trying to install dryscrape and when i write `!pip install dryscrape`
in google colab i get the following output:

> Collecting dryscrape
> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b5/75/c45f796ec5bc7f98c38b9ae425390ef5f4a76153c8b5af946adb97e7e622/dryscrape-1.0.tar.gz
> Collecting webkit_server>=1.0
> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/f2/f4f454cccde75e95359e91fa58f14497350dc97e58534f9003c77eca3dff/webkit-server-1.0.tar.gz (41kB)
> |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 2.5MB/s
> Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from dryscrape) (4.2.6)
> Collecting xvfbwrapper
> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/b6/4920eabda9b49630dea58745e79f9919aba6408d460afe758bf6e9b21a04/xvfbwrapper-0.2.9.tar.gz
> Building wheels for collected packages: dryscrape, webkit-server, xvfbwrapper
> Building wheel for dryscrape (setup.py) ... done
> Created wheel for dryscrape: filename=dryscrape-1.0-cp37-none-any.whl size=5440 sha256=8e8469df960b731a8cb688d85b0cd4abcdd0aa4bcf5805d817af8e91b57091c1
> Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/d5/7e/24/0b5b37166c524082a6fb722bc14c6f885ebb7fcfc7e1563f3e
> Building wheel for webkit-server (setup.py) ... error
> **ERROR: Failed building wheel for webkit-server**
> Running setup.py clean for webkit-server
> Building wheel for xvfbwrapper (setup.py) ... done
> Created wheel for xvfbwrapper: filename=xvfbwrapper-0.2.9-cp37-none-any.whl size=5009 sha256=0df17305d7fbff2973dddb1560c1e232f19fcc2a73be1dca2ed2a00d1a2c50f5
> Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/10/f2/61/cacfaf84b352c223761ea8d19616e3b5ac5c27364da72863f0
> Successfully built dryscrape xvfbwrapper
> Failed to build webkit-server
> Installing collected packages: webkit-server, xvfbwrapper, dryscrape
> Running setup.py install for webkit-server ... error
> **ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-irrofp8e/webkit-server/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-irrofp8e/webkit-server/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ufv_nemh/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.**

I tried installing from the github repository and i get the same output when i write `!pip install -r requirements.txt`, i was using the offical documentation.

Comment: It’s __scraping__ not scrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing to the logs error is regarding the `webkit-server` library and seeing in the GitHub issues of `webkit-server` the library came to the pull request, which helped me install `webkit-server` and then install `dryscrape` follow the below commands to install it in your Colab.

Command 1:
`!pip install git+https://github.com/niklasb/webkit-server.git@refs/pull/35/head`

Command 2:
`!pip install dryscrape`

This will successfully install `dryscrape`.

Output:
[image: Output]

Let me know if you have any questions :)